# Is there a python package - import mapping available?

Tags: python, pypi

When I run a python code and it imports a library that is missing an error is printed out that this library cannot be imported, for example

```
import cv2
import PIL
```

for order to install these two example packages, however, you have to install them as follows

```
pip install opencv-python
pip install pillow
```

So the names of the import and the package do not match.

Is there a central database/file etc. somewhere that contains the name of the package given the name of the import?

Comment: The inverse is possible, however there may be many packages using the same `import` name as others on pypi, so no.

Comment: I know different packages that have the same top-level directoies. `Cheetah` from `Cheetah2`, `Cheetah3` and `CT3`; different versions and maintainers of the same package. `Crypto` from different cryptography modules (I know at least two). So exact mapping is simply impossible though a mapping that's mostly correct still possible. Just not implemented.

Comment: So I am back to googling the most likely match when I need something...

Comment: If you have a library installed with `pip` you can lookup package metadata in `*.dist-info` subdirectories in `site-packages`.